# The textField is ignoring pattern for showing sum with currency

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a variable `V{Total}` where the pattern `###0.00` is not applied, what am I missing?

```xml
<textField pattern="###0.00" isBlankWhenNull="false">
    <reportElement uuid="ea9933c9-1863-474f-a6e2-65cfe3f07426" x="390" y="9" width="144" height="20" forecolor="#000000"/>
    <box>
        <pen lineColor="#999999"/>
        <topPen lineColor="#999999"/>
        <leftPen lineColor="#999999"/>
        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#999999"/>
        <rightPen lineColor="#999999"/>
    </box>
    <textElement>
        <font fontName="Verdana" isBold="true" isUnderline="false"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{Total}+".- €"]]</textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to format a string:

`$V{Total}+".- €"` will be a string, even if the the variable was decimal adding the `.-€` will turn it into a string, thus meaning your formatting won't work

What you need to do is format the value on its own and the add the trailing characters, try something like this:

```
new DecimalFormat("###0.00").format($V{Total})+".- €"
```

Full Solution:

```
<textField isBlankWhenNull="false">
    <reportElement uuid="ea9933c9-1863-474f-a6e2-65cfe3f07426" x="390" y="9" width="144" height="20" forecolor="#000000"/>
    <box>
        <pen lineColor="#999999"/>
        <topPen lineColor="#999999"/>
        <leftPen lineColor="#999999"/>
        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#999999"/>
        <rightPen lineColor="#999999"/>
    </box>
    <textElement>
        <font fontName="Verdana" isBold="true" isUnderline="false"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new DecimalFormat("###0.00").format($V{Total})+".- €"]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Comment: Excellent, you might consider accepting the above as the answer, to help other users know who stumble upon it.